# Disable latte dock panel resizing

Tags: kde, plasma

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 and latte dock. I have following problem: when I open a lot of apps and latte can't show all icons in panel, it resizes icons and fits all icons in panel. During this resize it changes panel width, it affects all apps (they adjust their sizes too). How to fix this annoying behavior?

Comment: In case you don't get help here, consider asking at  [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/). The Latte dock developer is present there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try increasing the Dock's maximum length.

1. Right click on the Dock.
2. Select Dock Settings.
3. Open the Appearance tab.
4. Scroll to find the Length section and increase the maximum length of the dock to 100% or whatever you like.

This should fix the problem as long as you don't fully occupy the length with your apps.

Comment: That does not answer the question at all. The question is about the case where the length is more than fully occupied with items.